# How to pass error from TypeConverter to ModelState errors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, typeconverter

I have implemented a `TypeConverter` to deserialize a type from string in query.

The type contains `Guid` and `Guid` in string could be invalid, so I want to pass error to ModelState.

I try to `throw new ArgumentException("my message")`, and it's working, but the error message from the exception is not passed to `ModelError.ErrorMessage`. Is there any way to pass the error message into `ModelError.ErrorMessage` or can I only get the message from `ModelError.Exception.Message`?

Comment: Why not `ModelState.AddModelError("my-field", "error-message")`?

Comment: @itminus where I can call it? `TypeConverter` has no access to controller `ModelState`

Comment: `ModelState` is available in Controller/ActionFitler/ModelBinder.  Could you please tell us how your TypeConverter  is  invoked?

Comment: I use attribute `[TypeConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]`

Comment: I think you should use a ModelBinder?

Comment: Yes, I use it, but in docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1 states `Typically shouldn't be used to convert a string into a custom type, a TypeConverter is usually a better option` so I try to use it :)

it looks like my case is a bit more complicated then "typical"

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see what you're trying to do.

Since the builtin ModelBinder will capture the inner exception of `FormatException`, in order to set the `ModelError.ErrorMessage`, we could throw(or re-throw) an new exception of `FormatException`. For example,

```
public class MyConverter : TypeConverter
{
    ...

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            try{
                ... 
                return new MyClass(x);
            }
            catch(Exception e){                 
                throw new FormatException("Ouch: sth happens");  // throw a FormatException
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    ...
```

For more details, see [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/SimpleTypeModelBinder.cs#L100-L106):

Comment: Message in `ModelError.ErrorMessage` will be correct, but the message from the exception is only transmitted in the case of `InputFormatterException` 

 https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Abstractions/src/ModelBinding/ModelStateDictionary.cs#L317